# too many arguments to function ' ' at this point in file

Tags: c, arguments, pass-by-reference

I'm having the problem...

error: too many arguments to function 'EPJ calc'
error: at this point in file

This code works perfectly if I reduce the number of variables to 6 instead of 11 in the whole process. Can anybody explain why, and a way around this? In the assigment I have to be able to repeat the process 10 times.

```
   void loop()
   {
   calc(&person[cc].reacTime[0], &person[cc].reacTime[1], &person[cc].reacTime[2], 
          &person[cc].reacTime[3], &person[cc].reacTime[4], &person[cc].reacTime[5], 
          &person[cc].reacTime[5], &person[cc].reacTime[6], &person[cc].reacTime[7], 
          &person[cc].reacTime[8], &person[cc].reacTime[9], &person[cc].midvaerdi);
     Serial.print("Average time for person ");
     Serial.print(cc);
     Serial.print(" ");
     Serial.println(person[cc].midvaerdi);  
   }

    struct EPJ calc(float *num1,float *num2,float *num3,float *num4,
                    float *num5,float *num6,float *num7,float *num8,
                    float *num9,float *num10,
                    float *midval)
   {
            float temp;
     temp  = (*num1 + *num2 + *num3 + *num4 + *num5 + 
              *num6 + *num7 + *num8 + *num9 + *num10);
     Serial.print("Temp number : ");
     Serial.println(temp);
     *midval = (temp)/nRepeat;
     Serial.print("midval number : ");
     Serial.println(*midval);
   }
```

Comment: do you have a forward declaration of `struct EPJ calc()` function? also, `&person[cc].reacTime[5],` is present twice !!!

Answer (score 2):

It looks you are calling calc with 12 arguments, but it is defined accepting only 11.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a simple *typo* error while calling `calc()`. You've supplied `&person[cc].reacTime[5]` twice as parameter.